# View Controller memory allocation and release - what is the correct way to do it

Tags: ios

I've wondered today about something.

Let's say I declare a property `MyViewController *myViewController` in my root `UIViewController` interface and implement it (synthesise, release, unload etc.)

I then have a function `loadMyView()`:

```
- (void)loadMyView {
    if (!self.myViewController)
        self.myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:self.myViewController.view];
}
```

and:

```
- (void)hideMyView {
    [self.myViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

These functions may be used several times.

The thing is, once I hide the view, I no longer need it along with its contents and their current state. So what is the correct way to remove it from memory allowing me to allocate again later (thus omitting the `if` statement in the `loadMyView` method) and why?

I need to have a strong pointer to the object for other reasons which is why I'm not creating a temporary object and then releasing it.

In `hideMyView` do I:

1. `self.myViewController = nil;`
2. `[self.myViewController release];`

or 3. Auto-release memory when initialising: `self.myViewController = [[[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil]autorelease];` (But when does it release?)

Still rather new to this.

Comment: Why are you loading a view controller in your `loadView` method? This method is for loading subviews in the current view. It seems you already have a view controller, so why is MyViewController needed? Create a UIView subclass with your view, and control it directly from your already existing view controller.

Comment: Does it matter why it's needed? I'd still like someone to explain. I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: Well, you asked about correct way of doing things, no? This is incorrect code, since MyViewController serves as only allocator. It will not receive `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear:` or `shouldRotateToInterfaceOrientation` and so on. So it is in fact incorrect.

Comment: That's ridiculous. Of course it does, it has it's own class (MyViewController.h/.m)

Comment: Just because a class is defined, does not mean someone will magically call these methods. Have you pushed an object of MyViewController into a navigation controller or presented a MyViewController modally? If not, then no one is passing calls to these methods.

Comment: What on earth are you talking about? An instance of the class has been initialised with a nib file, as soon as the view of that view controller is presented, the methods you speak of are called. I've had no problem implementing this, try it yourself.

Comment: From what you have posted here, this is not the case. How about posting more code?

Comment: Line 3 of `loadView` it's right there. I don't need to show the class itself, it's just a subclass of `UIViewController`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10300/discussion-between-leo-natan-and-sooper)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's confusing about your question is that loadview is one of the methods in the UIViewController class. It doesn't make sense to override the first view controller's loadview method in order to initialize a second view controller and add the second view controller's view property to the the first view controller's view property. I don't think your question provides enough context for anyone to give you an intelligent answer.

Comment: Crap! It was supposed to be `loadMyView`. Thanks for that.